# Creating Association for User Profile and User with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I am trying to create a user_profile model to use with Devise's User model

I have the following :

User Class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :user_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile

  after_create :build_profile

  private

  def build_profile
    user_profile.build_user_profile
  end

end
```

User_Profile Class

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, if: -> { self.username.present? }

  def build_user_profile

  end

end
```

My View (devise/registrations/new.html.erb)

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

When I open the page, I get the following error:

> undefined method `username'

I'm fairly new to associations -- and can't figure out why :username isnt being recognized (or what the correct way to do this would be).

I added an index column in User (user_profiles_id) through `belongs_to :users, :user_profiles` migration.  I also intend on overriding Devises registration controller.

Just can't seem to get this darn form to load.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `username` into a `fields_for` block:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>
  <div><%= profile_form.label :username %><br />
  <%= profile_form.text_field :username, :autofocus => true %></div>
<% end %>
```

It creates a scope around the specific model of the form `f`. More [info here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Comment: Thanks!  This eliminated the error -- but the form doesn't show up on the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nops, hard without any kind of trace or error message. Anyway, using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you don't need to use a callback (`after_create :build_profile`) to create the `user_profile`, it's more or less what it will do for you.

Comment: surprisingly, that was the issue.  once i removed `accepts_nested_attributes_for` it appeared.  Thanks!